# Capturing client/server TLS version in Python requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

Is it possible to see which TLS version was negotiated with the server using Python requests module?
Something similar to what `openssl s_client -connect` would return

```
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3043 bytes and written 375 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No error, I'm able to connect, but I want to see whether my connection is using TLS 1.2 :)

Comment: According to the documentation it looks like they use whatever is the urllib3 default is unless you specify differently. But without digging too much more, you could simply use wireshark to log the traffic and view the handshake protocol version in your capture. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version

Comment: @stephen yeah, "whatever is the urllib3 default" was my first idea, but Python does not make a lot of sense - documentation says one thing, the code says another one. Like I should have ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3, but ssl.py does not contain this code :D
Wireshark was my initial thought, but I'm in a commercial environment and it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the core of my other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55462022/6368697 if you want to do things just once and for tests, a monkey patching can be enough (and otherwise read the rest of my answer which offers a proper implementation with a transport adapter, and also proper display of certificates received):

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.connection import VerifiedHTTPSConnection

SOCK = None

_orig_connect = requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection.connect

def _connect(self):
    global SOCK
    _orig_connect(self)
    SOCK = self.sock

requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection.connect = _connect

requests.get('https://yahoo.com')
tlscon = SOCK.connection
print 'Cipher is %s/%s' % (tlscon.get_cipher_name(), tlscon.get_cipher_version())
print 'Remote certificates: %s' % (tlscon.get_peer_certificate())
print 'Protocol version: %s' % tlscon.get_protocol_version_name()
```

This yields:

```
Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256/TLSv1.2
Remote certificates: <OpenSSL.crypto.X509 object at 0x10c60e310>
Protocol version: TLSv1.2
```