# How to trust a server certificate using Python requests when I don't have access to the parent certificate

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

Using the Python `requests` library, how can I trust a server TLS certificate when this certificate mentions an issuer that I can't access (untrusted root)?

In other words, I'd like to trust the public key provided in the server certificate. I don't want to completely disable certificate validation, and ideally the solution would not prevent `requests` to validate other valid certificates.

Using `curl` and `openssl`, I can manage to get this result, but I am unable to reproduce this using the `requests` library, even using the `verify` parameter.

Using the URL https://untrusted-root.badssl.com, which exposes a certificate with an untrusted root:

```sh
# Certificate issuer is not trusted
$ curl https://untrusted-root.badssl.com             
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
...
# Download the server certificate locally to badsslcom.crt
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -servername untrusted-root.badssl.com -connect untrusted-root.badssl.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform pem > badsslcom.crt
# Now, curl accepts the server certificate
$ curl --cacert badsslcom.crt https://untrusted-root.badssl.com
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

The following Python code raises an exception however:

```py
import requests
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

url = "https://untrusted-root.badssl.com/"
cert = "badsslcom.crt"
if not os.path.exists(cert):
    raise ValueError('Can not find cert')
r = requests.get(url, verify=cert)
```

The exception is

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): untrusted-root.badssl.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 560, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 252, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 305, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 377, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 988, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 633, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 589, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_ssl.py", line 13, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url, verify=cert)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 588, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

How can I mirror the `curl` behaviour in Python? Adding the certificate to the Ubuntu 18.04 system store and pointing the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to the system store did not help either.

Comment: The note in this page might help: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: You will probably create a new adapter that override the default certificate check in order to do your own if you detect a specific certificate and go back to default handling for other cases. Have a look at this other answer of me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55462022/6368697 and see how I call _validate_conn()

Comment: @DroidX86 are you talking about the `c_rehash` utility? I'm not using a directory containing certficates, but a single certificate.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks, I may try this, but this seems awfully complex for something that curl handles natively.