# Is it normal, that get_client_ca_list() of pyopenssl fails with TLS1.3

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

**Update 2022-05-17:**
As TLS 1.2 will become more and more obsolete I'd really be interested in an answer for this question

**Question and Title updated 2021-04-02:**

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644890/python-ssl-eqivalent-of-openssl-s-client-showcerts-how-to-get-list-of-cas-fo) of how to get the list of permitted CAs for a given https server
And one person suggested using `pyopenssl`, which helped me solving my problem at the time.

So I tried out following code:

```
import socket
from OpenSSL import SSL

def get_client_cert_cas(hostname, port):
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
    sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
    # next line for SNI
    sock.set_tlsext_host_name(hostname.encode("utf-8"))
    sock.connect((hostname, port))
    return sock.get_client_ca_list()
```

It always returned no result.
After some playing around I came up with following solution:
Before calling `sock.get_client_ca_list())` I perform a handshake with `sock.do_handshake()`

And this worked for all web servers, that I encountered up to this point.

Now however I encountered an https server where the SSL endpoint is  on an `F5`
and now the code

```
def get_client_cert_cas(hostname, port):
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
    sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
    # next line for SNI
    sock.set_tlsext_host_name(hostname.encode("utf-8"))
    sock.connect((hostname, port))
    sock.do_handshake() # now client_ca_list will not be empty
    return sock.get_client_ca_list()
```

returns an empty result.

The openssl command `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -servername <hostname>`
returns well the correct result.

After Further investigation I found out, that the F5 uses TLSv1.3 and the 'working' servers used TLSv1.2

Now my last fix which is working is to force TLSv1.2

```
def get_client_cert_cas(hostname, port):
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
    # It seems I must ensure to not use TLSV1.3
    ctx.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_3)
    sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
    # next line for SNI
    sock.set_tlsext_host_name(hostname.encode("utf-8"))
    sock.connect((hostname, port))
    sock.do_handshake() # now client_ca_list will not be empty
    return sock.get_client_ca_list()
```

Is it to be expected, that `get_client_ca_list()` does not work with TLSV1.3 or is there an additional action to perform in the TLS1.3 case to have results for `get_client_ca_list()`?

Please note, that I don't insist on `pyopenssl` It is just the only solution, that I found so far.

If the problem can be solved with `cryptography` or any other package, then this is also fine with me.

Comment: What *OpenSSL* versions are you using (from *Python* and command line)? Also could it be that in the command line same thing happens, but fallback is automatically attempted? Check `openssl s_client -no_tls1_3 -connect ...` and see if you get the same result.

Comment: @CristiFati you might be onto something:
my openssl client was rather old and didn't support TLS1.3
(OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)

When running a newer openssl client (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020), then openssl 

displays 
`No client certificate CA names sent`
And only if I call it  with `-no_tls1_3` I get the desired `Acceptable client certificate CA names` output.

This seems to indicate that my real question is now whether it is normal, that TLS1.3 does not send client certificate CA names or whether this is a specific bug of the given F5 server

Comment: Good we have that sorted out. Now what about *OpenSSL* version used from *Python*? It should be a newer one since you experience the error. I don't know what the *F5* is, but seems like this server doesn't support *TLSv1.3*. So, the next logical step would be that in the code to apply the same principle that did the trick in command line: `ctx.set_options(OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_3)`, or add some logic: try getting the *CA* list and if empty, try with the above flag set.